# How can I swap the shift key with another key?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I'd like to swap the shift key with the `/` key. Ukelele says that it can't be used to change modifier keys. [DoubleCommand](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/) has static settings that you can either enable or disable. It doesn't let you chose your own custom bindings, and needless to say, this remapping I want isn't available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can swap shift key with some other with key using  [KeyRemao4Macbook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) but I am not sure can swap with `/` .

[image]

Comment: Nice! It let's you modify a Private.xml file and map your own keybindings which is exactly what I did to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

[PCKeyboardHack](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/extra.html) will do that.